# Fortran entries of array change seemingly at random

Tags: memory, fortran, gfortran

I have been working with a FORTRAN program. I have noticed seemingly random changes in a 1D matrix I'm working with. It is a matrix of 4000 integers. Values are added to the matrix one by one, starting with index 1 and iterating by 1 for each added value. The matrix does not get fully "filled", currently only 100 values are placed into the matrix. So one would expect that the first 100 entries of the matrix will be non-zero (all added values are non-zero) and the remaining 3900 entries will be 0. However, several of the entries of the matrix end up being large negative numbers, but I'm certain that no portion of my code touches these entries.

What could be causing this issue? I'm sorry but I can't post the code for you all to work with.

The code has several other large matrices, taking up a total of ~100 MB of space. Could this potentially be a memory issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your array, otherwise it will almost always contain garbage. This would do it:

```
array = 0.0e0  ! real array
```

or

```
array = 0.0e0  ! double precision
```

or

```
array = 0  ! integer
```

Comment: It is perhaps with noting two points.  In Fortran "initialize" means something specific, and not the assignment shown.  You probably don't mean `0.0e0` as double precision (and for each of the examples there is type conversion available).

Comment: You can just use `= 0` to initialize (define) whatever Fortran numerical type variable. Small integers are exactly representable.

Answer (score -2):

A "matrix" is two-dimensional; your array is one-dimensional.

Things do not change unless you ask them to change.

FORTRAN does not initialize variables other than (as I recall) in a labeled COMMON.  As such, they are guaranteed to start out with garbage values.  Try initializing your data with a DATA statement.  If you have to initialize a labeled COMMON, you will have to supply a BLOCK DATA subprogram.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have cured the issue.

Comment: No need to use common blocks and data statements, you can initialize variables in the declaration like integer :: arr(10,10) = 0.

Comment: Right, to be clear, I solved the problem by initializing with X(:) = 0

Comment: Your stride expression is not necessary. `x=0` should do the job.

Comment: This answer is wrong. In general the fortran compiler does not initialize anything. It can be flagged to the compiler, but it's definitely safer to do it in the code.